# Erro md5 offertoro

Tags: php, md5

Bom eu estou a criar um site, onde os usuários ganham pontos ao completar ofertas, e ao completarem o sistema dá pontos.

Contudo eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$oid = $_GET["oid"];
$amount = $_GET["amount"];
$id = $_GET["userid"];
$payout = $_GET["payout"];
$sig = $_GET["sig"];
$key = "Minha key";
$secret = md5($oid  + "-" + $id + "-" + $key);
$postback = 1;

if($secret == $sig){

    echo $postback;

}



?>
```

Ou seja se a sig for igual ao secret, o usuário é creditado com pontos, contudo eu estou a testar diretamente do site do offertoro e isso não está a funcionar, ou seja está me a dizer que o sig é diferente do secret, isso quer dizer que está alguma coisa de errado no secret.

Eu queria saber se a function md5, está a respeitar os parametros, ou se está alguma coisa de errado.

Key = 756ddad67f428a1db92ee0a2870005a4

Está aqui o site de onde tirei isto:

http://www.offertoro.com/docs

É só puxar para baixo que encontram.

Obrigado.

Comment: Faltou o ID da oferta e do Usuário. E essa linha tem erro: `$id = $_GET["userid"];`

Comment: Já consegui! o erro estava precisamento no "_" que estava faltando! Obrigado por me ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado ;) Para a proxima coloco mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá pra fazer muitos testes com o que foi postado na pergunta, mas uma coisa é certa: em PHP, não se usa `+` para concatenar *strings*.

Esta linha tem problemas:

```
$secret = md5( $oid  + "-" + $id + "-" + $key );
```

O correto:

```
$secret = md5( $oid . "-" . $id . "-" . $key );
```

Outro problema, faltou o `_` nessa linha:

```
$id = $_GET["user_id"];
```

Lembre-se que espaços e maiúsculas e minúsculas também fazem diferença para o `md5`

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar!